# Minkowski diagram and length contraction

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

The length contraction means that an object is the longest in the frame in which it is at rest.

Lets assume i have a meter stick with length $\Delta x$ in my rest frame which is $x,ct$ and i want to know how long my meter stick seems to an observer moving with a frame $x',ct'$.

**1st:** I draw world lines of a meter stick  in a rest frame and they are vertical (parallel to $ct$ axis) as meter stick is stationary in this frame.

**2nd:** If an observer in a moving frame $x',ct'$ wants to measure my meter stick he measures its edges at the same moment in his time, so i draw a tilted line (parallel to $x'$ axis).

**3rd:** If i mesure the length $\Delta x'$ which is a length of a meter stick as observer in frame $x',ct'$ sees it, it seems to me that **he sees a longer distance than me.**

This is not correct. Could anyone tell me what am i missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you've missed is that the distance along the $x'$ axis is not the same as the distance along the $x$ axis.  The locus of events that are 1 unit of proper distance from the origin is a hyperbola.  This can be used to calibrate the $x'$ axis.  See [calibration hyperbola](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Special_relativity:_kinematics#Graphic_representation_of_the_standard_Lorentz_transformation).

[image]

Comment: Thank you this allso contributed to the solution and it is a really good anwser. In fact i did add my own anwser after studying your anwser.

Answer (score 5):

One picture is worth a 1000 words here...
[image]

The important point is that we make a snapshot of the moving object in a time coordinate which is not its proper time. Indeed, if we drew just one image of the moving object in a cut given by $t' = \rm const.$, we would get a projection on the $x$ axis longer than $l_0$. But we must use $t = \rm const.$ instead if the measurement is done in the un-primed coordinate system. Thus, we measure the "front" of the object earlier (in terms of its proper time) than the "rear". The difference in $t'$ allows the latter to cover some extra distance, putting the two events closer in $x$. If the math is worked out, it indeed gives $l_1 < l_0$.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a graphical demonstration and you provided an excelent picture!

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about aditional options to explain this it returned to me, that in frame $c',ct'$ marks on $x'$ axis are further appart than marks on $x$ axis (pay attention to $1$ and $1'$). So my picture was correct from the beginning, but i didn't draw the marks on $x'$ axis. Thank you Alfred Centauri.

Well now it is obvious why moving observer sees shorter distance. Take a look at the picture and give me some feedback please:

[image]

**Q:** But what if a meter stick is stationary in frame $c',ct'$? I guess then $\Delta x'$ is the proper length and i have to transfer its edge points to $x$ axis using lines parallel to $ct'$ axis?

Comment: what did you use to draw the graphs?

Comment: I use inkscape.

Comment: Where you wrote "parabola" you mean "hyperbola"

Comment: @Marcel True. =)

Answer (score 0):

A and B have a mirror M on the end of a rod of length d.
In the A frame, the length of the rod is ct=d.
The red hyperbola, aka calibration curve, denotes the same A-time where it intersects the time line of a moving observer. Gamma=g.
Left:
Bt=2gt at the return signal, event D. B assuming a pseudo rest frame (because there is no absolute rest frame), perceives his signal to M as equal out and back, giving d=gct, greater than d.
Right:
With length contraction, B measures the B rod as ct=d.
A measures the length of the B rod as d/g.
B measures the length of the A rod (on the Bx axis) as d/g.
The results are reciprocal **only if** the B frame is affected by lc. 
[image: length contraction]